# Does "bumping" up and down a kerb damage my car?

Tags: suspension, opel, agila

My driveway does not have a dropped kerb, so every day I have to bump up and down the kerb.

Does this do any damage to my suspension or tyres doing this every day?

If I do it quickly (say at 5mph), will it eventually destroy my suspension?

The kerb is about 7cm high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The slower you go, the longer they'll last

All suspension components (springs, shocks, control arms) are made of materials that last for a certain number of cycles before failing due to fatigue.

How many cycles before failure will be governed by the stress that the suspension components are made to endure, which will depend on the height of the kerb and the speed at which the wheels hit the kerb.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about the suspension since cars are designed to do it, unless you drive at crazy speeds your suspension should be able to handle the kerb for a lifetime.

The component which might give in should be the damper or the oil seals, the coils are much more sturdier and wont be affected by this kerb , again I am exaggerating.

Bottom-line: Dont worry kerb wont damage your suspension if your are careful.